# A permanent navigation bar with UI elements

Tags: ios, objective-c

Our app has some upper view, that is visible all the time.
This bar has a `UITextField`, `UIButton`s, `side scroller`, and `segment control`, and they are dynamic.
When you hit them, the view behind them(full screen) is changing.

I was thinking about `navigation control`, or `tab bar`, but seems that they can't have a `text field` and a `scroller` on them.

So my main thought was to create some COSTUM view of my own.

Question is , how can I create a view in storyboard, and add it as a constant view, than create some other views(+viewcontrollers) that will be changed according to that upper bar?

I want to create 5 views in `storyboard`, and switch between them according to the bar.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a job for a containment view controller to me. I've used technique many times to both create a set of static controls on the screen which you describe and inject reusable content into an app in several locations.

The basic concept is:

1. Setup you Heads Up Display(HUD) with all the UI you want (this will be your base `UIViewController`).
2. Create a `UIView` in it and call it your `contentView` or something of the like. This is where all your dynamic content will appear.
3. Then your backing view controller adds another `UIViewController` as a child and tell it to show it's view in the `contentView` you specified.
4. Your view controller continues to remove and add children putting their content into the `contentView` as needed.

If you are unfamiliar with the technique there are many [tutorials](http://nscookbook.com/2013/08/ios-programming-recipe-28-view-controller-containment-transitioning/)(by NSCookbook) of do a web search for "view controller containment tutorial". There is also a good WWDC (2011) video introducing the concept [Session 102 - Implementing UIViewController Containment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/?id=102).

Comment: Thanks, i don't familiar with HUD. i wanted to create a layer in storyboard, and add it where ever i need. but according to your method, if i add the bar every time again when i move between scenes ir will look bad. i have to make it stay static, and replace just the views under it … is that what your link shows ?

Comment: the link you provide is very unclear to me . can you give me some direction on how to perform this ?

Comment: @Curnelious Did you watch the video?  It seems pretty clear to me.

Comment: @Curnelious: You create one view controller in your storyboard that contains your toolbar, and in it's code, use the view controller containment methods and normal `addSubview` /`removeFromSuperview` to add and remove the views of your other view controllers.

Comment: I organized the answer a bit more and added some more information and resources.